# Mysql group by and sum but only within the where clause

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the sum of pid within a where clause via a group by.

It works bar the sum looks at the entire table not the where clause.

The only way I can see to do it now is by making a temp table with the date limits but thought you could limit by the where clause.

```
SELECT t.pid, t.ocid, sum(t.pid) as tot FROM 
(select orders.oid as ooid, orders_content.oid as coid, 
orders_content.pid as pid,  orders_content.ocid as ocid 
from orders_content, orders
 WHERE orders.oid = orders_content.oid AND 
orders.status_date > '2014-07-19 09:20:04' 
ORDER BY orders_content.oid desc LIMIT 20 )t group by t.pid ORDER BY tot DESC
```

I understand Limit doesn't work with group by but thought limiting with the where clause would remove data before the date but the entire tables data is being summed via sum(t.pid)

Thanks

**EDIT**

added a fiddle here: [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50bbb3/8](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50bbb3/6)

as you can see the sum is was completely wrong as and count works!

Comment: Its quite unclear what you are asking. Please try explaining by giving sample data along with table structure and required output.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you've not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you've not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Your SQL fiddle gives exactly what I would expect for the test data. For the records in the date range you are interested there are 3 records with a pid of 8, 3 with a pid of 9 and 2 with a pid of 10. So for the pid of 8 it sums up the 3 values of 8 giving 24. For the pid of 9 it sums up the 3 values of 9 giving 27. For the pid of 10 it sums up the 2 values of 10 giving 20. What is it you want to calculate and what are your expected results?

Comment: @Kickstart yeh I answered my own question.. So dumb of me using sum() vs count() :(

Answer (score 0):

Reformatting your sql a bit I get this:-

```
SELECT t.pid, t.ocid, SUM(t.pid) AS tot 
FROM 
(
    SELECT orders.oid as ooid, 
            orders_content.oid as coid, 
            orders_content.pid as pid,  
            orders_content.ocid as ocid 
    FROM orders_content
    INNER JOIN orders
    ON orders.oid = orders_content.oid 
    WHERE orders.status_date > '2014-07-19 09:20:04' 
    ORDER BY orders_content.oid DESC LIMIT 20 
) t 
GROUP BY t.pid 
ORDER BY tot DESC
```

Looking at this it seems you are summing up the pid field, but with a *GROUP BY pid* , while ocid is in the SELECT but is not an aggragate value nor is it in the GROUP BY, hence the row with a matching pid that the value of ocid comes from is undefined. This doesn't appear likely to result in a meaningful value.